# How to decode JSON web token in clojurescript?

Tags: jwt, clojurescript, auth0

I've seen libraries like [buddy](https://github.com/funcool/buddy) and even [clj-jwt](https://github.com/liquidz/clj-jwt) but these all are used for clojure.  If I can use those libraries I can't figure out how to do it in my clojurescript application.

I'm able to include the files in the `project.clj` under the `:dependencies` with something like:

```
[buddy/buddy-core "0.13.0"]
[clj-jwt "0.1.1"]
```

But then I can't call them in my cljs files.  I suspect this is because they are clj files.

I was able to get the id token from the auth0 callback but now can't figure out how to read the token!  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Google Closure Crypt packages.
(https://github.com/google/closure-library/tree/master/closure/goog/crypt)

Here is an example where I used Md5 specifically (nothing to do with auth0, just showing how to use the crypt stuff.
https://github.com/timothypratley/snakelake/blob/master/src/snakelake/view.cljs

Comment: Thank you!  That lead me to the right direction.  I found that I could split the token and then get the values from it with that lib:  ```(println (b64/decodeString (second (clojure.string/split token #"\."))))```